# Advance queryset in django ModelAdmin. AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, django-modeladmin

I writing an app that has one Model User, with different roles.

So assign role I added a field in User model "user_type".

below is my User model.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICE)
```

It's working fine. I am able to do operation from Django admin site.

And now I want to display a count of the user in Django admin.

To do so I tried to customize Django ModelAdmin class.

Below is the Code.

```
class UserCount(User):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True


class UserCountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ("user_type", "count")

    def get_queryset(self, request):

        return User.objects.all().values("user_type").annotate(count=Count("user_type"))


admin.register(User)
admin.register(UserCount, UserCountAdmin)
```

And I get an error

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

I also check error on the internet, I found the same thing in Django issue but it was closed with the invalid status.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24387

Error traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 109, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 86, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 208, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 174, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 174, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 70, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 70, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 994, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 961, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/library.py", line 225, in render
    _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 339, in result_list
    'results': list(results(cl))}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 315, in results
    yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 306, in __init__
    super(ResultList, self).__init__(*items)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 217, in items_for_result
    f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 272, in lookup_field
    opts = obj._meta
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Please help how I can display data from queryset with values.

Comment: Can you post the *full* traceback?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that :

1. You're trying to annotate the `user_type` list, rather you should annotate the `QuerySet`.
2. You're returning `values`, instead you must return `QuerySet` from `get_queryset`

Try something like this :

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
        return User.objects.all().annotate(count=Count("user_type"))
```

Comment: Getting same error, the query you used giving same result, which given by my query.

Comment: Can you please check this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24387
Why django not supporting queryset with values.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: can this will give same result 
 User.objects.all().annotate(count=Count("user_type")), which give by me below query.  

select user_type, count(*) as total from user group by user_type

Comment: You can get the `values()` from queryset where you need that

Comment: Try to give any running example. I already checked above your query, it giving me all user, and what i want is, count of user by it's user_type.